# Jira - Restrict the Available Statuses by User

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

Currently, any user that has access to create a ticket on the Jira board can select any available "Status".  I am trying to restrict the ticket statuses that each user has access to.

For Example:
There are 10 team members and 10 total ticket statuses.  I want all 10 team members to have access to 8 of the ticket statuses, but only 2 of the team members to have access to the 2 remaining ticket statuses.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a [condition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/advanced-workflow-configuration-776636620.html) to the transitions to the statuses you want to restrict.

A "Permission Condition" is a *condition to allow only users with a certain permission to execute a transition*.